# Adding custom fonts to Tumblr

Tags: blog, fonts, tumblr

I'd like my tumblr blog to display a custom font, and to do so, I have to add the font directory to my blog by adding the URI (e.g url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.svg#FontAwesomeRegular').

If Tumblr hosts my blog, and I don't own any other web properties to host the font directory, where can I place the font directory so that I can link to it from my Tumblr blog? Or, is this not possible?

Answer (score 2):

If you have nowhere to host a custom font you may be best off using services like [Google Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts), [Typekit](https://typekit.com/), or something similar as their fonts can be loaded directly from a CDN.

CSS Tricks has a [good run down on the subject](http://css-tricks.com/google-font-api-interview/) and [Smashing Magazine has a good review of the sector](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/20/review-of-popular-web-font-embedding-services/)

Comment: Thanks--so just to clarify, there's no way to embed the font somewhere in the css, or add the font directory to the tumblr project so that tumblr hosts it?

Comment: Not so far as I'm aware. It's actually beneficial to you to host the fonts on a CDN, it's nothing to worry about